# java how to populate multiple JTextFields reading data from a .txt file

Tags: java, swing, text-files, readline, jtextfield

I have to read some data from a .txt file. Each row contains a string.
Each string has to be displayed in a specific JTextField.
How can i solve the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file line by line as described in the [Java Tutorial | Reading, Writing, and Creating Files](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html).

Call [`setText`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29) to set the text in a specific JTextField. e.g.

```
jTextField.setText(line);
```